# using master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have master page in asp.net.i want to display user in master page but in my knowledge master page is loading once at a time.How it possible when Session["User"] only get when login attempt.But master page is already loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The master page renders with each page request, so if you have code that dynamically populates data on the page (for example, setting a label in Page_Load) it will populate on each subsequent page load.  A master page can read from Session values just fine.

Have you tried something specific and it's not working?

Comment: Thanks @David i got a soln in ur answer.Thaks very much.Ur answer helps to clear my vision about master page.

Answer (score 0):

try to put a breakpoint in pageload of aspx.cs and master page. Page will load first. and after that master page will load. So session added from page can be accessible form masterpage